# Sort lines from file C

Tags: c, file, sorting

I simply want to read 10 lines from file, then sort them and print out. But something is wrong with my code, because when I have such file:

```
a
d
b

c

s
```

(notice a newline after 's') its sorts file but prints 's' twice:

```
a

b

c

d

s

s
```

when I remove a newline its all good. Where is the problem then? The most important parts of my code:

```
void sort(char **array, int filelinecount)
{
    int i, j;
    char t[LINE_MAX_SIZE];

    for(i=1;i<filelinecount;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<filelinecount;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(array[j-1], array[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(t, array[j-1]);
                t[LINE_MAX_SIZE] = 0;
                strcpy(array[j-1], array[j]);
                strcpy(array[j], t);
            }
        }
    }
}

    unsigned long int filelinecount = 10;
    char **array = (char**)malloc(filelinecount * sizeof(char*));
    char singleline[LINE_MAX_SIZE];

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<filelinecount; i++)
    {
        fgets(singleline, LINE_MAX_SIZE, fileIN);
        array[i] = (char*) malloc (LINE_MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        singleline[LINE_MAX_SIZE] = '\0';
        strcpy(array[i], singleline);

    }

    sortfile(array, filelinecount);

    for(i=0; i<filelinecount; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
```

Ok I will paste my WHOLE code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 4096

unsigned long int lineCountFile(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    unsigned long int linecount = 0;
    int c;
    if(fp == NULL){
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    while((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        if(c == '\n')
            linecount++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return linecount;
}

void sortfile(char **array, int linecount)
{
    int i, j;
    char t[MAX_LINE];

    for(i=1;i<linecount;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<linecount;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(array[j-1], array[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(t, array[j-1]);
                strcpy(array[j-1], array[j]);
                strcpy(array[j], t);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *in = "in.txt", *out = "out.txt";

    FILE *fileIN, *fileOUT;

    fileIN = fopen(in, "r");
    if(!fileIN)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    unsigned long int linecount = lineCountFile(in);
    linecount += 1;

    char **array = (char**)malloc(linecount * sizeof(char*));
    char singleline[MAX_LINE];

    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(singleline, MAX_LINE, fileIN) != NULL)
    {
        array[i] = (char*) malloc (MAX_LINE * sizeof(char));
        singleline[MAX_LINE] = '\0';
        strcpy(array[i], singleline);
        i++;
    }

    sortfile(array, linecount);

    for(i=0; i<linecount; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    fileOUT = fopen(out, "w");
    if(!fileOUT)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(i=0; i<linecount; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fileOUT, "%s", array[i]);
    }

    fclose(fileIN);
    fclose(fileOUT);

    for(i=0; i<linecount; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to set a conditional to recognize when you hit hte last new line.  You can do this by reading EOF/EOT too.

Comment: Does your file has exactly *filelinecount* lines (10)? Would be better to read until `fgets()` returns NULL.

Comment: Have you tried just reading in the data, and printing it out immediately to check that you're reading the data correctly?

Comment: `t[LINE_MAX_SIZE] = 0;` Array Out-of-Bounds

Comment: unnecessary `t[LINE_MAX_SIZE] = 0;` and `singleline[LINE_MAX_SIZE] = '\0';`

Comment: Name of the function is different `sort` and `sortfile`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: thanks:) pasted a whole code, could you help with this please?

Comment: @ring0: changed it as you suggested, pasted whole code but problem still exists

Comment: I think It work fine if you fix the part that you have pointed out.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: actually, Im getting seg fault right now :(

Comment: maybe `seg fault` at `singleline[MAX_LINE] = '\0';` this part delete

Comment: I think `qsort` will help you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine on my machine...

Just a note, *fgets* will read the *newline* character *\n* too into your variables, so when you print them like *printf("%s\n", myvariable)*, you will have an empty line between each line of output.

Also, after the final line is read, it will also read an **EOF** and, you shouldn't increment your **linecount** variable, else, you will get a segfault.

Cheers